# Komma vor "würden"

Tags: comma

Ich habe ein Problem mit folgendem Satz:

> Aufgrund Ihrer ausgewiesenen Kompetenz in der Raumfahrt, würden wir
>   uns freuen, wenn Sie daran Interesse hätten, ....

Ich würde hier vor "würden" kein Komma setzen, kann mir aber nicht erklären nach welchen Regeln man hier entscheidet. Über ein kurze Hilfe würde ich mich freuen.

Comment: Ich würde auch kein Komma setzen.

Comment: Man sieht an solchen Stellen zunehmend Kommas (die da nicht hingehören). Ich erkläre mir das damit, dass im Englischen (bzw. Amerikanischen) an einer solchen Stelle typischerweise ein Komma steht, und viele übernehmen das kritik- und gedankenlos.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Das Englische hat eine wesentlich laxere Einstellung zur Zeichensetzung als das Deutsche und betrachtet Kommata eher als eine Stil- als eine Regelfrage und *empfiehlt* in einem ähnlichen Satz, die "introductary phrase" durch ein Komma abzutrennen (ist aber kein "Muss"). Es ist nicht besonders empfehlenswert, da irgendwas zu übernehmen.

Comment: @tofro   Ja, das meinte ich.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Aufgrund* ist eine Präposition entstanden aus den zusammengezogenen Wörtern "auf" und "Grund" und leitet (genauso wie das fast bedeutungsgleiche *wegen*) keinen Nebensatz ein.

Und wo kein Nebensatz, da auch kein Komma.

Comment: .... und auch keine Einfügung, sollte man, möchte man gründlich sein, ergänzen.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Appositionen sind per se am Anfang eines Satzes nicht möglich, weil sie *das vorangegangene Wort* erläutern. (Aber nur, wenn man ganz gründlich sein will).

Comment: Ja, da hast du, muss man wohl zugeben, recht, am Anfang sind sie, außer man näme ein Nulllexem am Satzanfang an, technisch gesehen kaum möglich, denn wo sollte das einleitende Komma stehen? Oder... hm... muss eine solche Einfügung sich wirklich auf ein Wort davor beziehen, und muss sie wirklich mit Kommas beidseitig eingeklammert sein? **Wäre man phantasievoll, man könnte die Einfügung doch auch an den Satzanfang stellen!**